# Como obter o último dia do mês?

Tags: python, data, datetime

Estou tentando fixar uma data de vencimento para o final do mês porém não tenho ideia de como poderia ser o código. Atualmente está assim:

```
  from datetime import date
  from datetime import datetime
  from datetime import timedelta

  data_atual = date.today()
  print(data_atual)
  last_date = data_atual + timedelta(13)
  print(last_date)
```

Eu tentei fazer com `timedelta` porém tenho que ficar alterando o número para poder pegar o último dia do mês. Como faço para não ter que ficar alterando esse número?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é usar [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange), que retorna uma tupla contendo o dia da semana referente ao primeiro dia do mês, e a quantidade de dias daquele mês. Ou seja, basta pegar o segundo valor da tupla e setar este dia na data:

```py
from datetime import date
from calendar import monthrange

data_atual = date.today()
# monthrange retorna o último dia do mês, basta setá-lo na data e pronto
last_date = data_atual.replace(day=monthrange(data_atual.year, data_atual.month)[1])
print(last_date) # 2022-05-31
```

Outra alternativa (um pouco mais complicada) é primeiro setar o dia para 1, depois somar a quantidade de dias do mês menos 1 (assim, se um mês tem 31 dias, por exemplo, eu seto o dia para 1 e somo 30, resultando no dia 31):

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
from calendar import monthrange

data_atual = date.today()
# seta o dia para 1, e soma a quantidade de dias do mês menos 1
last_date = data_atual.replace(day=1) + timedelta(monthrange(data_atual.year, data_atual.month)[1] - 1)
print(last_date) # 2022-05-31
```

Se bem que esta solução é desnecessarimente mais complicada, pois se eu já sei a quantidade de dias do mês (obtida por `monthrange`), setar este valor diretamente é bem mais simples.

---

Outra forma igualmente mais trabalhosa é instalar o [pacote `dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) e usar um [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) para somar um mês. Depois, seta-se o dia para 1 e subtrai-se um dia. O resultado é o último dia do mês atual:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

data_atual = date.today()
# soma 1 mês, seta o dia para 1 e subtrai 1 dia
last_date = (data_atual + relativedelta(months=1)).replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
print(last_date) # 2022-05-31
```

É uma ideia parecida com a segunda solução acima, e também me parece desnecessariamente mais complicada. A primeira solução me parece bem mais "direto ao ponto".

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito!!!

Comment: +1 pela excelência presente na explicação!!